# Can't seem to curl from Nifi's ExecuteStreamProcess processor

Tags: curl, apache-nifi

I want to translate the following curl command:

```
curl -X POST -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d \'{\"text":\"Example message\"}\' <url>
```

This is how I configured my ExecuteStreamProcessor:

- Command Arguments = -X POST;-H \"Content-Type: application/json\";-d \'{\"text":\"Example message\"}\';
- Command Path = curl
- Ignore STDIN = false
- Working Directory = No value set
- Argument Delimiter = ;
- Output Destination Attribute = No value set
- Max Attribute Length = 256

Don't know what's the issue. The command run perfectly on terminal.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ExecuteStreamProcessor and not InvokeHTTP?

Comment: I did switch to that but I'm still curious why this won't run. I tried executing other system commands like ls, grep and df through ExecuteStreamCommand Processor and they ran perfectly.

Comment: Do you see exceptions when you try to run? and what OS are you running?

Comment: I have a very similar situation - what if my cURL command is as so: curl --proxy zproxy.lum-superproxy.io:22225 --proxy-user lum-customer-sourcewater-zone-XXX:XXX --request POST 'https://rrcsearch3.neubus.com/esd3-rrc/api.php?function=SearchImages' -H 'api_key: publicuser,api_sig: 68461babf138014f252e64732ef3b1a0' -d 'json={"Neusearch":{"profile":"15","Searchitems":{"item":[{"key":"district","value":"02"}]},"includeName":"","excludeName":"","excludeValue":"","recordFromDate":"","recordToDate":"","page":0,"pageSize":100,"strict":"true","saveSearch":"true"}}'

Answer (score 1):

```
-sSk;-u;username:password;--request;POST;--header;Content-Type:application/json;--header;Accept:application/json;--data;${data:toString()};https://restapiendpoint/
```

Use the above format in command arguments and put curl in command path.